# Is there any kind of standard for representing date ranges?

Tags: date, standards, naming, date-range, iso8601

[ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Calendar_dates) represents a date as `YYYY-MM-DD`.

It doesn't seem to offer any recommendation on how to represent a date range, for example:

```
2013-01-01 => 2013-06-31
```

Does ISO 8601, or another standard, give a sensible recommendation for representing date ranges?

*Background: this is to be used as the output of the `toString()` method of a `DateRange` object, output which could then be parsed with a `parse()` method.*

Answer (score 48, accepted):

ISO 8601 does have a standard for representing date ranges. To represent the start and end date using this format you would write:

`2013-01-01/2013-06-31`

Note how the forward slash is used as the interval designator to separate the start and end dates.

See the [ISO 8601 Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) for more information about time intervals.

Comment: If the leading part of the date is the same, you can omit it in the end date. So in this example the year is the same and it can be written as `2013-01-01/06-31`.

Comment: If you use Luxon and need a tiebreaker between this and Tim's answer, Luxon takes a '/' separator as the token to create an Interval.

Answer (score 27):

Just to add to Ben Smith's answer above, the standard also mentions using a double hypen (`--`) as the *interval designator* in certain contexts, instead of the forward slash (`/`). For example, in file or directory names where using a forward slash is forbidden in some operating systems (e.g. Windows).

So the above examples would be

`2013-01-01--2013-06-31`

or

`2013-01-01--06-31`

in abbreviated form

Comment: Is the abbreviated form actually a valid ISO8601? `--06-31` would be a valid date but if we use `--` as designator then the date here is written as `06-31` which doesn't seem valid.

Comment: @Jezor the link in Ben Smith's answer (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_intervals) seems to say so: "For <start>/<end> expressions, if any elements are missing from the end value, they are assumed to be the same as for the start value including the time zone."
So it's not a valid date in and of itself, but it is valid as the end of a date range.