# Specifying a date range in ISO8601

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, iso8601

In a string, `ISO8601` dictates a date be represented `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I have previously used `YYYYMMDD`, and in filenames have specified a date range as `YYYYMMDD-YYYYMMDD`.

With the date including a hyphen now, that way doesn't work, or atleast is unclear. Does anyone know of the 'correct' way to specify a date range in the `ISO8601` format, e.g. something like `YYYY-MM-DD-YYYY-MM-DD`?

Thanks,
Alexander

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20413843/10197418

Comment: @FObersteiner perfect, thank you ! shame about the forward slash because it can't be used in filenames, but a comment suggests just a double hyphen.
[sidenote, what am I supposed to do now with this question? I can't mark a comment as a solution, is there a way to simply close it?]

Comment: glad you found a solution. I can dupe-flag it, I don't know if you can close it yourself.

Comment: perfect, whatever you just did gave me pop up to say that link answers this question. it's now closed. cheers